# Map program, google earth plugin so

Tags: c#, maps

i will display my data on a Map and color specific some countries (own filter, and  i will show my own flight data and route data like: https://www.checkfelix.com/explore/VIE-anywhere 
I found  mapwingis but these would inlcude really work, so is a program out there what can help me with that ?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. For example: Are you looking for a c# library? What format are your data in?